# get and set values of a tag of html using dom model

Tags: javascript, html, dom, href, getelementbyid

I want to set value of a tag with document model

I need to set changeme value to something

How can i do that no jquery please

```
<a href="">changeme</a>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you add an identifier like this: `<a href="" id="href1">changeme</a>`, you can write `document.getElementById('href1').innerHTML = 'changed';`

Comment: Unfortunately, innerHTML is not compatible with all browsers. This is another reason I use jQuery, where you can specify either ('#href1').text('new text') or in this case ('#href1').html('new text)

Comment: To set the literal text, you can use `textContent` (all modern major browsers) or `innerText` (old IE versions). An universal method to set text is `o.innerHTML='';o.appendChild(document.createTextNode(string));` where o is a reference to the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need first to get a reference to the DOM element. There are numerous ways of doing this (the easiest is probably `getElementById`, so use that if you can give your link an `id`). If not, you could use `getElementsByTagName`:

```
var element = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0]; //Get the first `a` element
```

Once you have a reference to the element, you can change the text using the `textContent` property. Unfortunately, it's not quite that simple, because IE uses `innerText` rather than `textContent`:

```
if("textContent" in element) { //Check whether element has textContent property
    element.textContent = "Something new";
}
else {
    element.innerText = "Something new";
}
```

Comment: Eh. Use `'textContent' in element` instead of `element.textContent`. An empty string is also equal to false.